# SQL Query performs slower for another mysql version?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I'm working on a project which requires me to write an API for my users. I have written the following SQL statement so far and tested it on my localhost over my php:

```
SELECT topquery.kind_id,
       topquery.image,
       topquery.id,
       userquery.user_name
FROM `order` AS topquery,
     `user` AS userquery
WHERE userquery.user_id = topquery.user_id
  AND topquery.id IN
    (SELECT MIN(id)
     FROM `order` AS mainquery
     WHERE user_id != '$vUserId'
       AND id NOT IN
         (SELECT order_id
          FROM history
          WHERE user_id = '$vUserId')
       AND kind_id NOT IN
         (SELECT o.kind_id
          FROM history h
          INNER JOIN `order` o ON h.order_id = o.id
          WHERE h.user_id = '$vUserId')
       AND actions > 0
       AND kind = '1'
     GROUP BY kind_id)
ORDER BY vip DESC
LIMIT 35
```

This query takes about 0.5 secs on my localhost, and takes ~1.4 seconds on my server.

Now my question:
Is it possible that the speed of SQL queries can vary for each mysql version?
Or is my query just not "optimized" enough?

Comment: Did you try to check this query with explain (on local and production envs)?

Comment: There are many reasons why speed on different systems vary. It could be software versions, mysql server config, ram size/spped, cpu, disk speed, OS, data size etc. It's impossible for us to narrow it down with absolutely no info about those things (even then it would be hard).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be different, because every version of sql has different tweaks to be optimized or code path or algorithm processing speed. I think the latest version would faster than previous one.

Answer (score 0):

*off topic advice, but I wanted formatting so a comment isn't enough*

You commence your query using a join predicate within the where clause

```
FROM `order` AS topquery,
     `user` AS userquery
WHERE userquery.user_id = topquery.user_id
```

Yet deeper into the query you do use INNER JOIN syntax. So why not do this throughout?

```
FROM `order` AS topquery,
INNER JOIN `user` AS userquery ON userquery.user_id = topquery.user_id
```

Stick to using only explicit joins. Don't allow yourself to use commas between tables in the from clause. Don't "mix and match" join syntax, this leads to maintenance problems and possible bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Here I outline a diagnostic for your case, and then you can ascertain whether or not the speed is still actually a problem:

1. Network. Im not sure if thats time executed purely from SQL or if network time is in there as well. Your network call will incur an overhead.
2. It depends on what your server is, but if your environments are matched, it is almost always definitely because there is substantially more data in your server database than your localhost.

One of the plusses of having a shared dev server in a corporate context is that someone will probably put some data on there for you every so often, so everyone doesnt have to copy everything down to their machine to work with a real size data set. More data = more work = takes longer, simple as that.

3. You have a discrepancy in your database schema. If you arent in the position to rebuild your database in one command, you might've added an index on your localhost and forgot about it. You can use a schema tool to get the differences between your localhost and your database. I like SQLYog. I think Mysql workbench does it as well.
4. You have a discrepancy in your hardware. Ie your server is a 486 with 4mb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference in performance between servers**

Yes, performance can change between different MySQL versions. The reason is because the entire software might change, including the MySQL optimizer which calculates the plan that the query will be executed by.

Few factors I would check before deciding whether the MySQL version is the root cause are:

1. Hardware - do you have different hardware on your localhost and on your server? CPU, memory, hard drives, etc.
2. Allocated resources - Do you provide different memory allocations to the MySQL instance in my.cnf / my.ini configuration files on the different servers? If so, it can drastically impact the MySQL instance performance.
3. Caching - maybe the query was cached by the MySQL instance on one of the servers. I would suggest to restart the MySQL instance to make sure the caches are clear, and then run the query and compare the execution times.
4. Amount of data - do you have different amount of data in your localhost and the second server? If so, it can significantly impact the query execution time.

**Query Performance**

In addition, I looked at your query and it looks like it can be better optimized.

(I used [EverSQL SQL Query Optimizer](http://www.eversql.com?utm_source=stackoverflow) to get the recommendations - disclaimer, I'm a co-founder of EverSQL and humbly provide these suggestions):

1. You can replace the subselects (which are bad for performance) in the IN clause with an INNER JOIN.
2. You can replace the subselects in the NOT IN clause with a LEFT JOIN, which will improve performance.
3. Also, when you have complex sub queries, you can consider splitting them to temporary tables and join to those tables. The big advantage is that you can index the columns in that temporary table, join to it and once the session is done it will be dropped.
4. Make sure you add the relevant indexes (according to the data distribution in the columns and their cardinality). Make sure the indexes match the order of the conditions.

This is how the queries  will look like after optimization:

```
create table temp as 
SELECT
          o.kind_id
        FROM
          history h
          INNER JOIN `order` o ON h.order_id = o.id
        WHERE
          h.user_id = '$vUserId';

CREATE INDEX kind_id on temp(kind_id);

create table temp2 as
SELECT
      MIN(id) as id
    FROM
      `order` AS mainquery
      left join history h on mainquery.id=h.order_id
      left join temp t on mainquery.kind_id=t.kind_id
    WHERE
      user_id != '$vUserId'
      AND h.order id is null
      and t.kind_id is null
      AND actions > 0
      AND kind = '1'
    GROUP BY
      kind_id;    

CREATE INDEX id on temp2(id);

SELECT 
    topquery.kind_id,
    topquery.image,
    topquery.id,
    userquery.user_name
FROM
    `order` AS topquery,
    `user` AS userquery,
    temp2 AS temp
WHERE
    userquery.user_id = topquery.user_id
        AND topquery.id = temp.id
ORDER BY vip DESC
LIMIT 35
```

Comment: `The big advantage is that you can index the columns in that temporary table, join to it and once the session is done it will be dropped`. So, you will perform lexing + I/O after applying conditions, store that to a temporary structure, then lex + I/O that AGAIN, and that's faster than simply doing this whole thing ONCE? Your indexing strategy is.. index everything in where? Do you know what cardinality is? I can see you're promoting your own tool by answering MySQL questions but you're providing FALSE knowledge. I'm not going to downvote you, but please - ensure you're correct.

Comment: Well, section 8.2.2 in the MySQL optimization manual specifies that the optimizer can either choose to optimize an IN subquery to an EXIST clause or using materialization, which is actually creating a temporary table in memory (falling back to on-disk storage if the table becomes too large, which is often the case), that might be indexed or might not.
From my experience with Terabytes of data and complex queries, applying this change manually and not trusting the optimizer in this case, performs better and can provide up to 500% performance improvement.
Too long, adding one more comment.

Comment: Obviously, by using temporary tables we add some overhead to the query. However, this overhead is negligible, since creating the table will only take a few milliseconds more than it will take MySQL to materialize it.
Regarding the indexes recommendation - I agree it needs rephrasing (already done).
I'm trying to provide quality and helpful advice, but if there is anything I did against the community rules let me know and I'll learn from it.

Comment: I apologize if I seem abrupt, I'm just like that. I know you want to help, in the end - that's why we're all here for. I'm also experienced with larger data sets and I have to say that I had a different experience - manually creating temporary tables and indexing them nearly always proves less performant. However, there are many factors that need to be taken into account - from the hardware to what the query is supposed to do. Usually, queries that people produce can be rewritten to yield the same output with different approach. There's no "one fits all" advice with indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive opinion. I fully agree that there is no "one fits all" advice. I hope these advices will allow the OP to experiment with this query and maybe find useful improvements. If not, I hope he'll reply back with some more information and we might be able to provide more advice.